# How to wrap a React component by React.cloneElement using a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

For example, lets say I have the following routes:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
  <Route path='/home' component={HomePage} />
  <Route path='/profile' component={Profile} />
</Switch>
```

And I want to Wrap this components in a div, to pass a style and a new prop, using a function to be more reusable, like so:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/login' component={wrapper(Login, 'red')} />
  <Route path='/home' component={wrapper(Home, 'blue')} />
  <Route path='/profile' component={wrapper(Profile, 'green')} />
</Switch>
```

Where wrapper would be something like this:

```
const wrapper = (component, color) => {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
       <Component color={color} />
    <div>
  )
}
```

How is that possible? I tried some alternatives like:

```
const wrapper = (component, text) => {
  return React.cloneElement(component, {color: text})
 }
```

But not sure how I can do this using React.cloneElement or any other pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `render` prop instead of the `component` prop and pass the `color` prop to the components that way.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/login' render={(props) => <Login color="red" {...props} />} />
  <Route path='/home' render={(props) => <HomePage color="blue" {...props} />} />
  <Route path='/profile' render={(props) => <Profile color="green" {...props} />} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: I loved this. Any suggestion on how to wrap the component between a <div> </div> as well to add a style for example?

Comment: @LucasOliveiraSilva You could create a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) if you prefer, but it might be too cumbersome for this particular use case. If you want to surround the component with a `div`, you can also do that directly in the `render` prop.

Comment: The use case is an example, the original code is way complex. But That's good enough.